# InputStream when partial name is known? (Android)

Tags: java, android, file, io, inputstream

I'm gonna read a file whose name is partially known. Let's say I have few files like the followings:

- apple_5_34.jpg
- orange_3_67.bmp
- banana_1_13.gif

And I want to get the InputStream to those files when I only know the words "apple", "orange" or "banana".

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

Run in loop on all folder content and check `startsWith` case for all 3 defined above names.

Or run `regex` like:

```
[apple|banana|orange]+([\d\D]+)
```

or

```
/\b[apple|banana|orange][^\b]+\b/g
```

snippets of code

```
 InputStream in = null;

if(File[i].getName().matches("[apple|banana|orange]+([\d\D]+)")){
 in = new FileInputStream(File[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call `listFiles()` on the directory to get a File array, loop through it, check whether `File[i].getName().toLowerCase().startsWith("banana")` and if it does, get the `InputStream` for `File[i]`.

Comment: Perfect. Does it also work to list all files within `ZipResourceFile`?

Comment: If you can obtain a list of files inside the ZipResourceFile, yes. Can't find the documentation for the class, so I haven't checked.

Comment: @SamRad The `File` sees the `zip` type as file not folder so it will work to you too

Comment: `ZipResourceFile` is not a file. It's a class included in `APK Expansion Zip Library` which allows you to get an InputStream for known files. Actually that Zip contains my files. But your answer helped a lot. Thanks @Fess @Mike_SD